# Laravel 5.3 File Upload Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to upload image in laravel 5.3 using Ajax.

my blade code :

```
 <form method="post" class="inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input style="margin-top:0px;" type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="create1()">Create</button>
</form>
```

my ajax call :

```
 function create1()
{
    var photo = $("#file").val();

    $.ajax({
            url: '<?= URL:: to('store') ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            async : false,
        data:
            {

                'photo':photo,

            },
            success: function(e)
            {
                if(e == 0)  
                {
                     alert("Success Full Created"); 

                }
                else
                {   
                     alert("Error");
                }
            }   


    });


}
```

route call:

```
Route::get('store','admin\ProductController@store');
```

controller call:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = $request->all();

    $imageName =  $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $imagemove= $file->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

    $data123 = array (   "photo"=> $imagemove,  );

    $check222 = DB::table('product') -> insert($data123);   

  }
```

Comment: You're uploading a file via GET? It should be POST.

Comment: I've already tried with POST method in ajax. It shows me following error.MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: If you want to use a `POST` method, you need to use `Route::post()` and not `Route::get()`... So of course you're getting `MethodNotAllowed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step by step i will follow you

```
<form method="post" class="inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input style="margin-top:0px;" type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="create1()">Create</button>
```

Ajax Call

```
function create1(){

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $('#file').get(0).files[0]);

$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:<?= URL:: to('store') ?>,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        dataType:'HTML',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:data,
        success:function(data){
            if(e == 0)  
            {
                 alert("Success Full Created"); 

            }
            else
            {   
                 alert("Error");
            }
        }
    });}
```

Controller:-

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $post = $request->all();

    $imageName =  $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $imagemove= $file->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

    $data123 = array (   "photo"=> $imagemove,  );

    $check222 = DB::table('product') -> insert($data123);   
}
```

Comment: I got is error after puting your code.405 Method Not Allowed..Undefined variable: file

Comment: First Controller check "print_r($_FILES)"

Comment: i got this.Array();

Comment: var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $('#file').get(0).files[0]);

Comment: var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $('#file').get(0).files[0]); replace  var data = $('#file').get(0).files[0]; then check controller $_FILES

Comment: stil get Array ( )

Comment: and Undefined variable: file

Comment: https://jsbin.com/situhojuce/edit?html,console,output               this follow link js data value show

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to debug with your current solution, because you're using an AJAX request for uploading your files.

**You cannot upload a file via GET!**

So do the following:

- Disable the AJAX request
- Be sure your submit button has the `type="submit"`
- Change your route to `Route::post('store','admin\ProductController@store');`
- Test the upload

## Your html form should be:

```
<form method="post" class="inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input style="margin-top:0px;" type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
</form>
```

## Your routes.php or route file:

```
Route::post('store','admin\ProductController@store');
```

## Ok ... ?

If you're sure the upload works, insert your AJAX upload request.